# Loop through array in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Hi all I have a query using Linq that returns a set of records, one of which is the country id, I also have an array of desired countries. Is there a way of either looping through the countries array and seeing if the id is in the results, i want to do something like this

```
results = from r in results 
where
//jump to my c# array
for(int x = 0;x < array.count; x++)
{
r.countryId.ToString().Contains(array[x]) 
}
select r
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var list  =  from r in results
             where array.Contains(r.countryId.ToString()) 
             select r;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join the collections, but I think Yograj Gupta's answer is probably the better one.

```
var query = from a in results
            join b in array
            on a.CountryId equals b.CountryId
            select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the array type so assuming it's testclass1

```
    class TestClass1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
    TestClass1[] arrays = new TestClass1[30];

    countries.Where(x => arrays.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but i think this will work.

**UPDATE** : didn't notjce the array is of type country as well so. sorry.